# Security risk on handling preflight request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, cors

Ok, I was having an issue with a preflight (OPTIONS) request in an middleware component and, after much Googling, I found these lines that solved the problem:

```
if (string.Equals(httpContext.Request.Method, "OPTIONS", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    var response = httpContext.Response;
    response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpContext.Request.Headers["Origin"][0]);
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    return;
}
```

This solves the issue - I'm no longer getting an exception from the rest of the component because some custom headers I was using to authenticate are missing. (The browser doesn't send them for the OPTIONS request.) However, I am now worried about this line in particular:

```
response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", httpContext.Request.Headers["Origin"][0]);
```

Is that a security hole? I would expect that the origin is checked again on the actual request but I don't know enough about CORS to be sure of it. Should I figure out what domains I actually want to allow, and only allow those even for the preflight request? It's relatively complicated to get that information at that point, which is why I'm reluctant to do it if it's not necessary.

Comment: Reflecting arbitrary origins in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header while also allowing credentials _is_ indeed a security hole, because it amounts to negating most of the benefits of the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Cross-origin attackers will be able to steal your users' sensitive data. See https://portswigger.net/research/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for-bitcoins-and-bounties. You should indeed validate incoming origins against an allowlist.

Comment: You can store the allowed origins in configuration or env file and load it from there and check the header against it. So when you get concrete information, it will be just a setting change. But yes, currently you are blatantly allowing all origins which means you are disabling CORS in essence.

Comment: I agree that I am basically disabling CORS, but only for the OPTIONS (preflight) request. Isn't the origin checked for the actual request? I see the headers being returned by the server for the GET/POST requests, and those do have a whitelist for the domain. (Why .NET doesn't treat OPTIONS the same as everything else I don't know...)

Comment: instead of allowing all the origins, you could try to allow specific ones that need for a successful pre-flight request. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.example`. [Preflighted requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests) .

Comment: Agreed, @Deepak-MSFT, but as I mentioned getting those is rather complicated at that point, and I was wondering if it's necessary or not. I would prefer not to complicate the code for something that would ultimately be useless.